# ¿Obtener la hora actual Codeigniter 3x?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Necesito obtener la hora actual para insertarla en la base de datos, he probado usando el helper de CI

```
$this->load->helper('date');

now();
```

He probado con esta función pero me inserta

> ```
> 00:00:00
> ```

Saludos muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

La función `date()` da formato a la fecha/hora actual.

Más información sobre los posibles formatos que se pueden pasar como parámetro en http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

muy probablemente el error le tengas en la construcción de la TABLA en MySQl, 
¿Cual es el tipo de dato del campo (DATE,TIME, TIMESTAMP...) ?

Prueba ha hacer un echo de la variable con la hora de CodeIgniter para ver por donde viene el problema.

Otra opción es establecer la hora en MySQL

`date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`